# ldap comparing 2 users based on roles

Tags: ldap, rank

I have an LDAP with several users and each user can have 1 or more roles. I want to be able to compare 2 users and determine which user has a higher "rank" based on the permissions afforded by the roles.

So far the only thing I can think of is to have a numeric value for each role and then for each user either sum all roles values or just grab the highest. So my questions are:

1. Is there an industry standard approach to this or is the concept too varying across organizations/domains?
2. Can you suggest a better approach?

I realize this can be an open ended question but I have not been able  to get a concrete answer out of google, so any help is appreciated. If this is not the right forum to ask, can you suggest another?

*edit for clarification*

The problem I'm trying to solve is data sharing between users based on their rank.

Simple scenario: basicUser<HighUser<admin

HighUser should be able to share with other HighUsers and admin but **not** with basicUser.

With a single role like above it is simple but I was wondering if there is a better approach than what I've said above when more than 1 role

Comment: Why do you want to do this, assuming that it's even meaningful? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jarmod edited for clarification based on your question